# Volumetric lighting clipping / not displaying in cycles (not camera clipping related)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, displacement, volumetrics

Im following a [blender guru tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJ_OcBh7F5I) on clouds, but my displaced plane does not light properly once set as a volume (neither scatter nor principled volume works).

You can see it working for him at 20:54

For some reason when you move around the viewport in rendered view, the area which is lighted is always changing, but never lights it completely. Even though the lighting and plane are staying constant. (Isn't fixed in an actual render)

I thought it was a normals issue, but flipping doesn't seem to fix it.
Based on other forum posts I've also changed the camera clipping values, but this also doesn't fix it.

[Here's a download of the blender file](https://we.tl/t-HmWtNINMeB)

[image: Here are two slightly different angles giving completely different results in lighting]

[image: Here are two slightly different angles giving completely different results in lighting]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am following the same tutorial and am getting the same issue where the bottom of the clouds render as the the scene background color.

Comment: Nope, sadly not. Happy new year!